# Plot a histogram of text values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Let's say I have a list of text values (i.e., names), and I want to plot an histogram of those values, with the xticks labeled with those names.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
listofnames = ['Al', 'Ca', 'Re', 'Ma', 'Al', 'Ma', 'Ma', 'Re', 'Ca']
a,b,c = plt.hist(listofnames)
```

First of all, this code gives an error

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

which I don't have on my complete program (with a list of >2k names, with no more than 12 different names). I haven't been able to see why this simple example list gives an error while the complete one doesn't.

But the actual point is: I can do the histogram, but the bins are not labeled with the names. How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) function:

```
plt.xticks( arange(5), ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue') )
```

Complete example (by the way, your code doesn't work for me, but instead of your error, I get `TypeError: len() of unsized object`, so I'm histogramming manually here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
listofnames = ['Al', 'Ca', 'Re', 'Ma', 'Al', 'Ma', 'Ma', 'Re', 'Ca']
import collections
x = collections.Counter(listofnames)
l = range(len(x.keys()))
plt.bar(l, x.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(l, x.keys())
```

[image: example histogram]